# Datatables Jquery error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fnFilter'

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var selectedColumn = $('#columnlist').find(":selected").text();

$('#csearchtext').bind("change paste keyup", function () {
    var input = $('#csearchtext').val();

    console.log(input);

    $('#table_id').fnFilter('',4);
});

$('#dblist').on('change', function () {

    var selected = $('#dblist').find(":selected").text();
    tablefill(selected);

});

$('#search').click(function () {

    var selected = $('#dblist').find(":selected").text();
    tablefill(selected);

});

function tablefill(selected) {
    $('.advsearchbar').show();
    $('#stable').show();

    $('#table_id').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": '/php/connect/searchtablequery.php',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "db", "value": selected });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "calldate" },
            { "mData": "recordingfile" },
            { "mData": "uniqueid" },
            { "mData": "src" },
            { "mData": "did" },
            { "mData": "lastapp" },
            { "mData": "dst" },
            { "mData": "disposition" },
            { "mData": "duration" },
            { "mData": "userfield" },
            { "mData": "accountcode"}],
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf",
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                }]
        }
    });
}
```

});

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fnFilter' 
I am not sure why this is happening the jquery is included because the datatable is being created just fine. Any help on this will be great.

Comment: can you show me where your displaying it?

Comment: As in the site that it is hosted on ?

Comment: just like the table layout because when it happened to me i did not have enough rows in my aoColumns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to chain with dataTable object, like this..

```
$('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilter('', 4);
```

Comment: That got the error to go away but the table is not filtering anything lol

Comment: You try to filter with an empty string!

Comment: i derped forgot to change it to a variable, Thank you will mark as answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the dataTable object, instead of the jQuery object.

```
$('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilter('',4);
```

From the docs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Sometime later - filter...
  oTable.fnFilter( 'test string' );
} );
```